# Store order value in collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I want to order a collection.

I need to store a field `order` storing an incrementing numerical value.

So all the docs have values 1,2,...,n.

The problem is that the different docs belong to different projects (by `projectId`) so I cannot just have a "normal auto-incrementing" field.

How is this normally done? I guess I could use something like

```
var lastDoc = MyCollection.findOne({ projectId: projectId }, { sort: { order: -1 } });
var nextOrder = lastDoc ? lastDoc.order + 1 : 1;
```

every time I insert the documents. Is this correct? What if I delete one of the docs between the other docs?

Comment: I'd argue that this is not normally done. If you can tell us what exactly you're trying to accomplish (instead of how you're trying to accomplish it) we can help.

Comment: I just want to sort the docs manually so I guess I will have to store the order in a field in the collection and change this field when manually reordering the collection

Comment: what is the sort criteria?

Comment: If all the docs are in one collection, it doesn't matter whether they have different projectIds - you can still sort on `order` and make it auto-incrementing.

Comment: How do I make an auto-incrementing field in Meteor?

Comment: @MattK I want the user to manually drag and drop the docs to order them